# How to change activity image and text according to listview item click in android studio ? java or kotlin

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, kotlin

I'm making an android application for information of different places. There are more than 200 places. So creating each activity for each place is hard. So how can I change information of single activity according to listview item clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use arrays for your images and strings

```
String text[] = {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", ..............}
int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, ..............}
```

Then on your listview's OnItemClickListener;

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) { 
      yourTextView.setText(text[position]);
      yourImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
      } 
 });
```